# Proof that $T_pM=T_pU$, i.e. local identification of a tangent vector on a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $U$ an open set in it. Show that for all $p\in U$, $T_pM$ can be identified with $T_pU$.

I'm trying to prove the above - suppose I define $\imath :T_pU\to T_pM$ such that $\imath(v)(f)=v(f|_U)$. In the book I'm reading (Semi-Riemannian Geometry by Newman), it says that it can be easily shown that $\imath(v)$ is a vector and it can be shown that $\imath$ is a linear isomorphism.

Note that by this point, the book hasn't talked about the dimension of the tangent space itself, rather the dimension of a manifold. So I don't want to use the logic that $\imath$ is a map between vector spaces of the same dimension, so just prove that $\imath$ is injective. I'm stuck in a couple of places:

1. Proving that $\imath(v)$ is a vector
2. Proving that $\imath$ is surjective

For the first part, I need to show that it satisfies Leibniz rule. So
$$\imath(v)(fg)=v\big((fg)|_U\big)=v(f|_Ug|_U)=f|_Uv(g|_U)+g|_Uv(f|_U)=f|_U\imath(v)(g)+g|_U\imath(v)(f)$$

The problem is that on the RHS I should've gotten $f\imath(v)(g)+g\imath(v)(f)$ to properly prove Leibniz rule. Instead I have the restricted to $U$ versions of $f$ and $g$. How to proceed?

For the surjective part, I have an idea but not sure: suppose $v\in T_pM$. Define $u$ as an operator that acts on $C^{\infty}(U)$ functions (suppose $f'\in C^{\infty}(U)$) like so: $u(f')=v(f)$ where $f'$ is a restriction of some $C^{\infty}(M)$ function $f$ to $U$. What I can do is use a bump function to extend $f'$ to some $\tilde f$ such that $f'$ and $\tilde f$ agree on some $\tilde U\subseteq U$. This gives me a way to define $u$'s action: $$u(f')=v(\tilde f)$$ where $\tilde f$ is the extension of $f'$ to $M$ via the bump function at $p$. The first thought that comes is:
$$u(f'g')=v(\tilde f\tilde g)=\tilde fv(\tilde g)+\tilde gv(\tilde f)=\tilde fu(g')+\tilde gu(f')=f'u(g')+g'u(f')$$
But the problem is again that $f'$ and $\tilde f$ agree only in $\tilde U$, **not** necessarily in $U$. I can't just blindly interchange $f'$ and $\tilde f$ in the first and third equalities, so again how do I prove the Leibniz condition?

Comment: The canonical injection $TU\to TM$ is simply the differential of the inclusion $U\to M$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly: The functions need to be evaluated at $p$ in the Leibnitz rule. That is the Leibnitz rule for a derivation $v \in T_p (M) $ is that
$$v(fg) = f(p) v(g) + g(p) v(f)$$
for all $f,g \in C^\infty(M)$.

The missing ingredient is the following (which you also need to show injectivity):

> Let $v \in T_p(M)$ and $f,g\in C^\infty(M)$. If there exist an open neighborhood $U \subset M $ of $p$ with $f|_U = g|_U$ then $v(f)=v(g)$.

This shows that derivations are truly local objects, which leads to the (in my opinion much better) local definition of the tangent space in terms of derivations of germs of functions.

Comment: Thanks! So what you said resolves the first doubt I had. But for the second doubt, I'm still not sure how the first and third equalities (in the last equation in my question) should be valid. Could you guide in that?

Comment: @ShirishKulhari Firstly you need to show that $u$ is well defined. In detail you need to show that  $u(f^\prime)$ only depends on $f^\prime$ and not on the chosen extension of $f^\prime$. Then $\tilde{f} \tilde{g}$ is an extension of $f^\prime g^\prime$ so the first equality follows. The third equality is just the definition.

Comment: Ah my bad, third equality was obvious. So the first equality follows because $f'g'$ and $\tilde f\tilde g$ agree at $p$, and _$v$ is an operator defined "only at $p$"._ If it were some globally defined operator $\Theta$ that has meaning outside of the domain where $f'g'$ and $\tilde f\tilde g$ agree, in _that_ case we couldn't have said that $\Theta(f'g')=\Theta(\tilde f\tilde g)$

Comment: @ShirishKulhari It is not just that they agree at $p$ but that they agree on some open neighborhood of $p$ and that $v$ only "cares" about what happens in a (arbitrarily small) neighborhood of $p$, although perhaps this is what you meant.