# Proving surjectivity of isomorphism between $T_pM$ and $T_pU$

Tags: differential-geometry

This is a follow-up to this earlier question of mine: [Proof that $T_pM=T_pU$, i.e. local identification of a tangent vector on a smooth manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4739323/proof-that-t-pm-t-pu-i-e-local-identification-of-a-tangent-vector-on-a-smoot)

I'm trying to show an isomorphism between $T_pM$ and $T_pU$. More specifically I want to show that $\imath:T_pU\to T_pM$ with $\imath(u)(f)=u(f|_U)$ for all $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$, is surjective.

Let $f\in C^{\infty}(M)$ and $v\in T_pM$. Define $u$ as an operator acting on $C^{\infty}(U)$ functions such that $$u(g)=v(\tilde g)$$ where $\tilde g$ is ***an extension*** of $g$ to $M$ via ***a bump function*** at $p$, which means that $g$ and $\tilde g$ agree on some open nbd $U'$ of $p$ such that $U'\subset U$. So now we have $u(f|_U)=v(\widetilde{f|_U})$, but $\widetilde{f|_U}$ agrees with $f$ in some nbd of $p$, so by an earlier result, $$v(\widetilde{f|_U})=v(f)=u(f|_U)=\imath(u)(f)$$

But the problem is, I don't see how the way I defined $u$ gives a unique value (i.e. $u$ doesn't seem to be well-defined). There can be multiple bump functions at $p$, so potentially multiple extensions of $g$ to different $C^{\infty}(M)$ functions, leading to potentially different values when $v$ acts on those extensions.

Is there a way around this? Some better way to define $u$ or would a completely different approach would be needed to prove surjectivity?

---

Edit: Define $u$ as an operator acting on $C^{\infty}(U)$ functions such that $$u(g)=v(\chi g)$$ where $\chi g$ is an extension of $g$ to $M$ via a bump function $\chi$ at $p$. Now to show that this is well-defined - let $\chi'$ be another bump function at $p$. By definition, $\chi=1$ on some nbhd $V\subset U$ of $p$, and $\chi'=1$ on some nbhd $V'\subset U$ of $p$.  Thus $\chi=\chi'=1\implies h=\chi-\chi'=0$ on the nbhd $V\cap V'$ of $p$.

Denote by $\tilde g_{\chi}$ the extension of $g$ to $M$ via the bump function $\chi$. We need to show that $v(\tilde g_{\chi})=v(\tilde g_{\chi'})$. This is where I'm now stuck.

Comment: It's probably simplest to identify $T_pM$ with equivalence classes of smooth curves in $M$ passing through $p$ rather than point derivations. Under this definition, the isomorphism is obvious. You can then translate this back to the point derivation definition if you want.

Answer (score 1):

So in general the idea of the identification of $T_pM$ and $T_pU$ really boils down to the fact that derivations at $p$ act on functions defined locally around $p$. So we'd expect that your definition should be independent of the choice of bump functions.
**This is indeed the case:**

Let $\chi_1,\chi_2$ be two different bump functions around $p$. Define $h=\chi_1-\chi_2$. Note that we have for some nbhd $\tilde{U}$ of $p$ that $h|_\tilde{U}=0$.
Now just use the fact that $v$ is a derivation at $p$ as well as the result you mentioned, i.e. that $v$ only acts on "germs" of functions

$$v(hf)=h(p)v(f)+f(p)v(h) = 0$$

Indeed $h(p)=0$ and $v(h)= v(0) = 0$ (the latter by the aforementioned result and the fact that $h|_\tilde{U}=0|_\tilde{U}$).
Linearity then gives $v(\chi_1f)=v(\chi_2f)$ so we are done.

Comment: Just for some clarity, what you write as $v$ is what I wrote as $u$ in my question, right? And what you write as $f$ is what I wrote as $g$ in my question? So in your answer, essentially $v\in T_pU$ and $f\in C^{\infty}(U)$ and $\chi_1f, \chi_2f$ are extensions of $f$ to the whole of $M$ that you proved are the same. Do I have that correct?

Comment: @ShirishKulhari No, because we need $v\in T_pM$ as it acts on a function on $M$, so it should be the same $v$. The notation I changed was $\tilde{f_U}=\chi f_U$

Comment: Thanks, give me a bit of time and I'll edit my question to include a revised approach after looking at your answer. Would be grateful if you can check that whenever you get time

Comment: I'm running into a slight problem when reading through your proof. Note that we have to show that $v(\chi_1 g)=v(\chi_2 g)$, where (in your notation) $\chi_i g$ is the $C^{\infty}(M)$ function (that we get by using the bump function $\chi_i$) that agrees with $g$ in an open subset of $U$. But this is just notation - $\chi_i g$ can't literally mean $\chi_i$ multiplied by $g$ since one is $C^{\infty}(M)$ and the other is $C^{\infty}(U)$. The (ill-defined) definition that I have in my question only references a $C^{\infty}(U)$ function $g$ and its extension via bump fn.

Comment: @ShirishKulhari Just choose functions $\chi \in C^\infty_0(U)$  (Compactly supported smooth cut off functions) with $\chi=1$ in a nbhd of $p$ in your definition. Then $\chi f$ is well defined and we can smoothly extend it by zero to $C^\infty(M)$.

Comment: Fair point, but in $\chi f$, you're taking $f$ to be a $C^{\infty}(M)$ function, right? What I'm saying is, we can't have $\chi g$ as well-defined, where $g\in C^{\infty}(U)$. And if you meant that $f\in C^{\infty}(U)$ and there's some way to extend $\chi |_U f$ to $M$, that part isn't clear to me. I did try on my end (see the edit to my question), but no success.

Comment: @ShirishKulhari So $\chi f_U\in C^\infty(U)$ can be extended to some function $F\in C^\infty(M)$ by zero. Note that  $F=\tilde{\chi} f$ with $\tilde{\chi}$ being the extension of $\chi$ by zero. Then the argument should work. The notational sloppiness again stems from the fact that $v$ acts on locally defined functions anyway which we can always extend by 0.